# Help identify the discrete component in this battery pack

Tags: batteries, identification

I am rebuilding a NiMH battery pack for a RF remote control device which can be recharged by plugging the device in.

The battery pack is connected with three wires:

- black to the negative
- red to the positive
- BLUE through a mysterious discrete component to the negative

[image: battery pack]

The component in line with the blue wire looks a bit like a glass-body diode but my multimeter cannot measure a diode voltage. (It measures infinity, not zero, if this helps.)

However, I can measure about 11.5 kOhm across the component in both directions.

**Can anybody enlighten me, what this component is likely to be?** I would like to verify that the component is still functional because it is unclear whether or not the device still charges properly.

Comment: remotely related: [Why are there 3 pins on some batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/10588/7036)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Its a **thermistor** like this (photo from internet, not spam related):

[image: Photo from internet]

This kind of resistor depends on the temperature of both batteries.

*EDIT*: In this photo, is a **N**egative **T**emperature **C**oefficient. There are also **P**ositive **T**emperature **C**oefficient resistors. The main difference between them is how the resistor decreases or increases when the temperature grows, respectively.

That's a cheap component and a cheaper way to determine when both batteries are charged up.

When a NiMH is almost charged, its temperature starts to grow. If you measure the temperature based on a voltage divider into a DAC, you can measure the temperature and, therefore, activate the charge or deactivate it.

*EDIT*: The thermistor must be **very close** to the batteries to read a correct value, so that's why this discrete component is located close to the batteries.

The temperature based graph to read when *stop* charging the battery is like this:

[image: Photo from internet]

Related: [Voltage input for charging NiMH Batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/voltage-input-for-charging-nimh-batteries)

If you can measure the temperature, you can check when it's charged up.

Comment: +1 your answer is much better than mine.

Answer (score 10):

It is a thermistor. This senses the battery temperature, so the charger can know when something goes wrong.

Measuring it likely won't tell you if the battery pack is still working correctly, though.

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense. I should have thought of that. Easy to verify and not very likely to break. - Many thanks!